How extract endpoint path template in Tapir
Is there any way to extract the endpoint path template as input for Tapir endpoint (to be used inside of the serverLogic)? Something like
in(extractFromRequest(_.uri))
but not from ServerRequest but from Endpoint
So instead of /create-user/john I would like to get /create-user/{username}

The method you are looking for is showPathTemplate from Endpoint object.
Just doing something like the following would be enough to get that value
endpoint
  .in("some-path")
  .in(path[String]("some-user"))
  .showPathTemplate() // this returns /some-path/{some-user}

showPathTemplate the method has some params if you need to customize the value returned

A full example to use the template path inside your business logic could be like the following
// just a case class to use it as an output response
case class PathAndUserResponse(path: String, user: String)

// the json serialization, in my case I use jsoniter for this example
implicit val jsonCodec: JsonValueCodec[PathAndUserResponse] =
      JsonCodecMaker.make

// the endpoint definition without the businessLogic
val endpointSpec = endpoint
  .in("some-path")
  .in(path[String]("some-user"))
  .out(jsonBody[PathAndUserResponse])

// the template path is just an string
val templatePath = endpointSpec.showPathTemplate()

// the endpoint with the logic implemented using the template path
val fullEndpoint = endpointSpec
  .serverLogic[Future](user =>
    Future(
      Right(
        PathAndUserResponse(
          templatePath, // the template path extracted from the endpoint definition used inside the business logic
          user // the user received in the path param
        )
      )
    )
  )


A unit test that validates you are getting the expected output following the docs from tapir - testing. In this case I'm using scala test
lazy val stubBackend =
  TapirStubInterpreter(SttpBackendStub.asynchronousFuture)
    .whenServerEndpoint(fullEndpoint)
    .thenRunLogic()
    .backend()

val userValue = "user-value"

basicRequest
  .get(uri"https://test.com/some-path/$userValue")
  .response(asJson[PathAndUserResponse])
  .send(stubBackend)
  .map(_.body.value should be(PathAndUserResponse(templatePath, userValue)))


From the scaladoc of showPathTemplate
  /** Shows endpoint path, by default all parametrised path and query components are replaced by {param_name} or {paramN}, e.g. for
    * {{{
    * endpoint.in("p1" / path[String] / query[String]("par2"))
    * }}}
    * returns `/p1/{param1}?par2={par2}`
    *
    * @param includeAuth
    *   Should authentication inputs be included in the result.
    * @param showNoPathAs
    *   How to show the path if the endpoint does not define any path inputs.
    * @param showPathsAs
    *   How to show [[Tapir.paths]] inputs (if at all), which capture multiple paths segments
    * @param showQueryParamsAs
    *   How to show [[Tapir.queryParams]] inputs (if at all), which capture multiple query parameters
    */
  def showPathTemplate(
      showPathParam: (Int, PathCapture[_]) => String = (index, pc) => pc.name.map(name => s"{$name}").getOrElse(s"{param$index}"),
      showQueryParam: Option[(Int, Query[_]) => String] = Some((_, q) => s"${q.name}={${q.name}}"),
      includeAuth: Boolean = true,
      showNoPathAs: String = "*",
      showPathsAs: Option[String] = Some("*"),
      showQueryParamsAs: Option[String] = Some("*")
  ): String

you can also see the value showPathTemplateTestData from EnpointTest with different endpoint definitions and the expected output
  val showPathTemplateTestData = List(
    (endpoint, "*"),
    (endpoint.in(""), "/"),
    (endpoint.in("p1"), "/p1"),
    (endpoint.in("p1" / "p2"), "/p1/p2"),
    (endpoint.securityIn("p1").in("p2"), "/p1/p2"),
    (endpoint.in("p1" / path[String]), "/p1/{param1}"),
    (endpoint.in("p1" / path[String].name("par")), "/p1/{par}"),
    (endpoint.in("p1" / query[String]("par")), "/p1?par={par}"),
    (endpoint.in("p1" / query[String]("par1") / query[String]("par2")), "/p1?par1={par1}&par2={par2}"),
    (endpoint.in("p1" / path[String].name("par1") / query[String]("par2")), "/p1/{par1}?par2={par2}"),
    (endpoint.in("p1" / auth.apiKey(query[String]("par2"))), "/p1?par2={par2}"),
    (endpoint.in("p2" / path[String]).mapIn(identity(_))(identity(_)), "/p2/{param1}"),
    (endpoint.in("p1/p2"), "/p1%2Fp2"),
    (endpoint.in(pathAllowedCharacters), "/" + pathAllowedCharacters),
    (endpoint.in("p1" / paths), "/p1/*"),
    (endpoint.in("p1").in(queryParams), "/p1?*"),
    (
      endpoint.in("p1" / "p2".schema(_.hidden(true)) / query[String]("par1") / query[String]("par2").schema(_.hidden(true))),
      "/p1?par1={par1}"
    ),
    (endpoint.in("not" / "allowed" / "chars" / "hi?hello"), "/not/allowed/chars/hi%3Fhello")
  )

also it is the method used in the observability module to add the labels
import sttp.tapir.server.metrics.MetricLabels

val labels = MetricLabels(
  forRequest = List(
    "path" -> { case (ep, _) => ep.showPathTemplate() }, // here
    "protocol" -> { case (_, req) => req.protocol }
  ),
  forResponse = Nil
)


Thanks for the answer.
Sorry I was not precise. I need path template as an in part of the endpoint. Basically my business logic need it in serverLogic. I cannot call it from outer scope.

@Matzz I edited my answer adding an example of how you can do that and also a unit test. Let me know if that is what you are trying to achieve.
